# How to specify digits and imeOptions together in XML of Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, digits, imeoptions

In Android EditText I found a strange issue. I have put `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` and it worked correctly but when I specified digits as `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "` I haven't Next option in the edit text. Why does it happen and what should I do to have imeOptions with digits?!

Answer (score 0):

Use android:inputType="number" and android:imeOptions="actionNext". This will work. If you want something different change the inputType (numberDecimal/number/numberPassword).

Comment: I need to specify digits and inputType doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to write `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "`  to Prevent  user to type invalid characters ..
if I Right , you have to use   `android:inputType="` attribute Or make ValidationClass.Java To filter user income ..

[+] For more information about `android:inputType="` follow this  [this](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style) .

[+] For more information about `android:imeOptions` follow [this Explanation with Video](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/imeoptions)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why digits and imeOptions don't work together

Comment: Actually, I don't know..but I searched more and more and saw that this problem is still a problem that many programmers have not solved .. but I saw responses to their problem indicating that they should use android: inputType = ".. and after that I responded to you. I hope it helps you.

Comment: not at all .. you can check this awesome library .. maybe it will do what you want 
https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. The part about restricting to letters only, don't do it for XML. Otherwise by code: "InputFilters", otherwise imeoptions and digits will not work together.

For example:(Work for TextInputEditText or EditText is the same)

1.XML: (here your imeOptions)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etOwner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_48"
                        android:maxLength="40"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_owner"/>
```

2.But, in code: Will create an input filter for the text input.

class InputLettersFilter.kt

```
class InputLettersFilter: InputFilter {
    override fun filter(
        cs: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        end: Int,
        spanned: Spanned?,
        dStart: Int,
        dEnd: Int
    ): CharSequence? {
        var filtered = ""
        for (i in start until end) {
            val character = cs[i]
            if (Character.isWhitespace(character) || Character.isLetter(character)) {
                filtered += character
            }
        }
        return filtered
    }
}
```

3. And lastly you add it to the input in your fragment , activity, etc.

   mBinding.etOwner.apply { filters = arrayOf(InputLettersFilter())}

digits and ImeOptions do not work together if digits refers to letters "ABC....abc..."